# UPS Time-Left calculation

Tags: batteries, ups

(Note: this is not a "repair" question - I have already decided I need to replace either the battery or the whole UPS)

I am probably overlooking something really obvious here, but... here goes.

I have an UPS with an (almost) brand-new [sealed lead-acid 12V battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004FV7XJG), three months' service life, holding 7 Ah of charge. So, that would be ideally an energy of 84 Wh. Taking into account a 20% deep-discharge margin (I don't want to go below 20% charge), and a further 10% loss in DC-to-AC conversion, that would leave me with 60 Wh of useable AC energy.

The UPS reports a load of 15% of its 540W nominal value, and additionally reports a load of 82 W. This makes sense, as 15% of 540W is 81W and some reporting approximation can be expected.

Now, in my book, having 60Wh of energy and needing to supply 82W of power translates into an autonomy of about 44 minutes (60 / 82 is 0,73 hours).

The same UPS (and a crude testing, consisting in unplugging the AC cord while holding a stopwatch) reports an autonomy of about *four minutes* - exactly one tenth of what I would expect. This with what is reported as a full charge (100%), with battery voltage reading correct.

If it was under its advertised load (540W), draining six times more current, I expect it would die in about *forty seconds*. This cannot be the expected performance.

What could be the issue here? Running the calculations in reverse I conclude that *it must be the battery that is defective, and only holds 0.7 Ah instead of the advertised 7 Ah*.

What baffles me is how can the UPS know this (since the "4m" time left estimate is spot-on). I don't quite believe it integrates the charge current over time.

So, either the defect lies elsewhere, or the UPS does not behave like I thought. This kind of information was not detailed in the documentation, so I'd love to be enlightened.

Comment: @LSemi This site is for questions on electronic design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weak battery's voltage drops much more quickly than a good one. The UPS simply stops working under certain conditions:

1. The device(s) connected demand too much current to start.
2. The current demand, depending on cooling of the UPS output devices and their efficiency, is enough to cause overheating.
3. The battery voltage drops below the value required by the inverter, probably about 11 V.

Clearly, with a rating of 540 W (or V-A) and a drain of 82 W, neither 1. nor 2. apply, so most likely the battery is quite weak (or there is a high resistance at the connectors - try mashing them shut a bit, if loose on the terminals). You can put a voltmeter across the battery while you redo your test, and watch the voltage drop.

As for the measurement or estimation of battery condition by the UPS, that is likely done under load, e.g. switching to battery power or applying a temporary load resistor drawing 10 or more amperes. The [internal battery impedance](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/rising_internal_resistance) is calculated from the current and voltage drop, and that shows the remaining life. That principle is used to determine automotive battery health. Notebook PC's using Li-ion batteries, on the other hand, actually use the integrated charge/discharge, which is why occasionally the [ACPI charge system may need to be reset.](https://www.drivers.com/update/pc-fix-tips/why-is-my-laptop-battery-not-charging/)

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed that I didn't think of doing this immediately, just in case. But to tell you the truth, I'm not too hopeful, because I don't see how the UPS could *know* this beforehand. If the battery was weak, the UPS should tell me "Go, Will Robinson! You got 40 minutes!" and then die on me after a tenth of that time. It actually *warns* me that I only have those four minutes. (Can it *really* be integrating the charge current? Granted, it's a very fine APC UPS, but this would be approaching magic :-D ).

Comment: @LSerni, it *might* be integrating the charge/discharge, as laptops do. A more effective way to estimate lead-acid (not Li-ion) battery charge state is to put a heavy load on it for a short time (<1 second) and note the voltage *under load*. That is the principle used by automotive battery checkers: a *huge* metal-ribbon load resistor that draws perhaps 50 amps, across a voltmeter, to check output under load. The UPS might check for 0.1 seconds every ten minutes, or some arbitrary schedule.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and the UPS does make a soft "click" every half an hour or so, followed by a slight buzzing noise that lasts perhaps two seconds. I imagine that it switches the load to AC power, and tries stress-testing the batteries. If you add this to the answer I'm accepting it.

Comment: @LSerni, thanks; edited.